# Why nested functions within DOM event handlers fix the 'this' binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

A simple question, that I haven't managed to find an answer to. If I handle a pass a method to a DOM event handler, `this` references the DOM element:

```
$('#foo').click(shapeA.describe);
```

Whereas if I wrap it in a function, it references the parent object (i.e. the effect that you most often want):

```
$('#foo').click(function() { shapeA.describe(); });
```

I know that I can use various techniques such as `bind` to ensure predictable behaviour. But what I would like is to understand the difference between the two lines above.

I found an article ['Understanding the this keyword'](http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/), which states that:

> If we call a function as a property of an object using either dot (i.e., obj.foo()) or bracket (i.e., obj“foo”) notation, this will refer to the parent object in the body of the function

Which fails to explain this behaviour. This article may not be correct, but it was the best I have found so far!

So, can anyone explain this behaviour in the context of the rules relating to 'this'?

Here's a fiddle, if needed http://jsfiddle.net/PcLF3/

Comment: Because `shapeA.describe` evaluates to a function object which is *independent* of the `shapeA` object. That is, methods in JavaScript are *not bound* to objects implicitly, and `this` is set merely based on the *current receiver* (or as affected by `apply`, `call` or `bind`).

Comment: In your first case, `this` is not the global, it's the correct DOM object http://jsfiddle.net/LBZSk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
$('#foo').click(shapeA.describe);
```

You're passing in the `click` function the `describe` method ***without the `shapeA`***. `shapeA.describe` is just how you reference the `describe`. The code inside `click` does not know that the `describe` is from the `shapeA` object and it will be invoked in the current DOM context.

In your second case, `this` inside the anonymous function is the current DOM object.

```
$('#foo').click(function() { 
   console.log(this);// `this` here refers to the current DOM object
   shapeA.describe(); 
});
```

But `this` inside the `describe` will be the `shapeA` as you call it by using dot notation: `shapeA.describe();`

Comment: Aha - that makes perfect sense. Thank you!